# Python socket not sending host name

Tags: python, sockets, asyncore

I am using an asyncore.dispatcher client on python to connect to a server developed in LabWindows running on a PC. Here's the code snippet on the client that connects to the server:

```
class DETClient(asyncore.dispatcher):

   def __init__(self, host, port):
      asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
      self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      self.connect((host,port))
```

On the server side, my Labwindows code is looking for two parameters, TCPPeerName and TCPPeerAddr:

```
GetTCPPeerName (handle, peerName, sizeof (peerName));
GetTCPPeerAddr (handle, peerAddress, sizeof (peerAddress));
```

It seems that the python code is not passing the hostname at all, because my server gets a NULL for PeerName.

Do I have to do anything to specifically make the asyncore client to send the PeerName when establishing a connection?

Comment: How are you "looking for" TCPPeerName ? It isn't yet clear what you mean, but I suspect that you don't have a [reverse DNS mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) for your client PC.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I revised the question to better reflect the situation I am dealing with. I am developing the server in Labwindows. I do not know if the GetTCPPeerName relies on reverse DNS queries to get the hostname, but I think it is rather unlikely that it does.

Comment: What is the return value of [`GetTCPPeerName`](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370051V-01/cvi/libref/cvigettcppeername/)? If it is negative, what is the value of [`GetTCPSystemErrorString`](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370051V-01/cvi/libref/cvigettcpsystemerrorstring/) ?

Comment: `GetTCPPeerName` returns a value of -20, and the value of `GetTCPSystemErrorString` is "Information not available".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Do I have to do anything to specifically make the asyncore client to send the PeerName when establishing a connection?

No, you don't, because TCP clients don't send names when establishing a connection. They send addresses.

`GetTCPPeerName` is almost certainly calling `gethostbyaddr(X)`, where `X` is the address returned by `GetTCPPeerAddr`. In your case `gethostbyaddr()` is failing because the information is not available.

This means that your hostname resolution database is missing some data -- you might need to update your DNS, your hosts file, your WINS data, or wherever your host name data lives.

Answer (score 0):

IS that DETClient the actual implementation? Because it's missing instantiations of both host and port for that instance?
in self.connect you're using self.host and self.port, which both evaulate to None since you havent set them yet.

```
class DETClient(asyncore.dispatcher):

  def __init__(self, host, port):
    self.host = host #<---- this is missing
    self.port = port #<---- this is missing
    asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
    self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.connect((self.host,self.port))
```

Comment: I corrected the original post to reflect what the code looks like.

Comment: Ok. When the socket is trying to connect, the receiving side will determine the hostname from the packet itself, not from the application-level payload. Is it possible a tunnel or some other routing issue is getting in the way?

Comment: Right. There is no routing or tunneling between the two computers (the one running the python client is a raspberry pi and the server is a PC). The two are connected via switch with no other devices on. I have tried finding the function that establishes the connection, and so far, I have decided that _socket.connect_ex must be the one, but I don't seem to be able to find the file _socket.py, any ideas?